# Could QTWebView really pass the Apple App Store Checking?

Tags: ios, qt, app-store, appstore-approval, qtwebengine

Because QTWebView  actually is using QTWebEngine, so I wonder if it could be passed? (I am using Qt5.4 to develop iOS app)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it will be rejected if found by the reviewer. See

> 2.17 Apps that browse the web must use the iOS WebKit framework and WebKit Javascript